# Add sfinae to a constructor allowing only the boost::geometry point types

Tags: c++, boost, sfinae, boost-geometry

boost::geometry provides for planar Cartesian coordinates two classes to define a point, using a given floating point type (double, float, ...):

(assume `namespace bg = boost::geometry;` in the following)

With FPT being the desired floating point type (float, double, ...):

```
bg::model::point<FPT, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> pt1;
bg::model::d2::point_xy<FPT> pt2;
```

(unrelated note: the second type is being inherited from the first one).

([ref1](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_point.html), [ref2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_d2_point_xy.html))

Now say I want a constructor taking a boost point as single argument for some class.
How do I write this, so that it will be selected only for these two types (because there are other single argument constructors in the class)?

For example, say I have this, where the constructor for boost points needs to be "sfinaed":

```
template<typename FPT>
struct Point
{
    FPT x,y;
    template<typename BPT> // Boost Point Type
    Point( const BPT& in )
    { /* code here */ }
    template<typename T> // other type
    Point( const T& in )
    { /* code here */ }
};
```

I [read here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_point.html) that the boost point classes must comply to a concept that states that:

> there must be a specialization of traits::tag, defining point_tag as type

So I tried this ([live here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7q7x8njW)) but there must be something I am missing, because it fails to build, with the classical

> template argument deduction/substitution failed

```
template<typename FPT> // Floating Point Type
struct Point
{
    FPT x,y;

    template<
        typename BPT,   // Boost Point Type
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<
                bg::traits::tag<BPT>,
                bg::point_tag
            >::value,
            BPT           
        >::type* = nullptr
    >
    Point( const BPT& pt ):
        x{ bg::get<0>(pt) }, // maybe add some static cast here
        y{ bg::get<1>(pt) }
    {}
};

int main()
{
    bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> pt1;
    bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> pt2;
    Point<float>  p1(pt1);
    Point<double> p2(pt2);
}
```

Those errors are still particularly difficult for me to track down...
Any idea?

Comment: Which c++ version?

Comment: Are your sure you check is correct. For me this fails: `static_assert(std::is_same<bg::traits::tag<bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>>, bg::point_tag>::value);`

Comment: Say, C++14, or C++17?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you comment. I' m just trying to use the described concept.

Comment: Also, why not just `Point( const bg::model::point<FPT, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>& pt )`?

Comment: `bg::traits::tag<bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>>` is not same type as `bg::point_tag`, so your check fails anyway...

Comment: Yes, indeed! I didn't think about that, it works because the second type is inherited from the first one, so automatic conversion happens. Consider adding that as second answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, constructors don't have return types didn't you know? ;)

Here you go:

```cpp
template<typename FPT> // Floating Point Type
struct Point
{
    FPT x,y;

    template<class BPT>
    Point( const BPT& pt, typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<bg::traits::tag<BPT>, bg::point_tag>::value           
    >::type* = nullptr)
    :
        x{ boost::geometry::get<0>(pt) }, // maybe add some static cast here
        y{ boost::geometry::get<1>(pt) }
    {}

    template<class Other>
    Point(const Other&) : x{0}, y{0} {}
};
```

Note: If C++20 is an option, concepts would be the ideal solution rather than SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I know! ;-) But the sfinae machinery always look like black magic to me!

Comment: Can be just `Point( const std::enable_if<std::is_same<bg::traits::tag<BPT>, bg::point_tag>::value, BPT>::type& pt)`

Comment: Nice answer, but @sklott made me realize that sfinae wasn't even required, as the two allowed types are related, see https://godbolt.org/z/TE5zM3qea

Comment: @sklott Absolutelly! Worth an edit or even another answer I'll make sure to upvote.

Comment: @kebs SFINAE **IS** black magic. This is not a feature designed into the language but an emergeant, _discovered_ property.